# Why are there 2 different memory addresses for a single pointer? - C

Tags: c, pointers, memory, nodes, allocation

Some context.. I'm trying to create dynamic tree in C, and i'm basically nearly done.

The thing is, currently, I'm stuck with a segmentation fault which seems it has something to do with passing a pointer of my current node (which is a struct "TABLEAU") to a function..

When passing TABLEAU *current into addNewBetaNodes(), I try to print the address of the current node once and once only (printing was for debugging - I had no other way of finding out what was going on)...

```
  void addNewBetaNodes(TABLEAU *current, char *subStringLeft, char *subStringRight) {

  printf("addNewBetaNodes *current = %p\n", (void *)current);
```

However, I get the following output when running the program:

```
addNewBetaNodes *current = 0x7f9b45c02c20
addNewBetaNodes *current = 0x7f9b45c02c50
```

For some reason, there is now 2 different memory addresses for the one pointer?

Can someone please explain why/how this is happening. It'd be highly appreciated

```
void addNewBetaNodes(TABLEAU *current, char *subStringLeft, char *subStringRight) {


printf("addNewBetaNodes *current = %p\n", (void *)current);

  if((current->left == NULL) && (current->right == NULL) && (current->straight == NULL)) { //IF NODE IS LEAF
    current->left = new_leaf(current, subStringLeft);
    current->right = new_leaf(current, subStringRight);
    printf("Made new beta nodes: %s   AND: %s\n", (current->left->formula), (current->right->formula));
    printf("addNewBetaNodes() Current: %p\n", (void *)current);
    printf("addNewBetaNodes() Current->left: %p, Current->right: %p\n", (void *)current->left, (void *)current->right);
  }

  else if((current->straight != NULL) && (current->left == NULL) && (current->right == NULL)) { //IF NODE IS UNARY
    addNewBetaNodes(current->straight, subStringLeft, subStringRight);
  }

  else if((current->left != NULL) && (current->right != NULL) && (current->straight == NULL)) {
    addNewBetaNodes(current->left, subStringLeft, subStringRight);
    addNewBetaNodes(current->right, subStringLeft, subStringRight);
  }
}
```

Comment: Include a true [mcve] how do you call `addNewBetaNodes()` ? Note: "TABLEAU" mean "array" in english ;)

Comment: Bet you that the pointer has two different addresses in the two prints because you changed the pointer between the two prints. MCVE, please.

Comment: you called the function twice. You got your first printf only (the big if that calls the second printf didnt yeild 'true'). First one has 'current' second one has 'Current'

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve it to get no warnings. **Use the debugger [`gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/)**, and perhaps [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). For your next question, provide some [MCVE]. The current one is unclear, since without any.

Answer (score 3):

Your printf() is printing the contents of current as a pointer, there is no reason to expect current to be the same between different function invokations. In fact for this functin I would *expect* the contents of current to be different.

Even if you were to print &current instead it would not be surprising to get different results, that would just depend on where the current variable happens to land on the stack.

Comment: @Yunnosch
I don't printf() The contents of the pointer, I print the memory address and I only print it once. However, it surprisingly is printed twice. Nothing else happens to the 'current' pointer except the print, so there isn't any reason for it to be printed twice. I don't change the pointer anywhere.

Comment: All I expect is that the address of the pointer passed into the function is printed as the address it was before it gets passed into the function.

However, when I try to print the address, to see what's going on.. One of the addresses matches the address of the passed pointer, but an additional address is also printed for some unknown reason. 

The question I want to ask is why :(

Thanks for your time!